How much leverage would an advantageous position for trade give in a post-collapse period?
Welcome to the Old Empire*, or what is left of it. After a catastrophic collapse for reasons I have not figured out, this pre-modern empire ceased to exist entirely, leaving the region I am focusing on destabilized and with a massive power vacuum.
Many small, independent states soon sprang up from the rubble, fiercely vying with their neighbors for power, prosperity, and stability. Among these states is Okri, a city-state situated in an advantageous location for trade**. Okri used its status as a great trade hub to deter aggression from its neighbors, instead signing treaties with them to ensure stability and help improve trade (treaties that are advantageous to Okri). Over time, Okri strengthens these treaties until it annexes its neighbors. Rinse and repeat for a couple decades to a couple centuries, and Okri turns into the Thukri Empire.
Or that's how I think it would work. The problem is I don't know if a city-state in a highly volatile region after the collapse of central government could use trade effectively for political leverage. On one hand, I know that, throughout history, trade has been instrumental in gaining the upper hand in geopolitics. However, I also know that, after the collapse/decline*** of empires, trade often breaks down or is much reduced.
So, answerers, how much political/diplomatic leverage could a city-state wield in a post-collapse era based on a good geography for trade alone?

Some additional info:

Based roughly on early medieval era in Europe, although borrowing influence from around the world (or trying to, at least)

All central government has collapsed; there isn't much, if anything, keeping the myriad of states together

Okri used to be a trade hub for the Old Empire, so it has infrastructure built up for trade (warehouses, docks, markets, etc.)

I intend on Okri conquering primarily through promises of wealth and stability, but they are not above using military force if it is "in the interest of prosperity and stability."


Footnotes:
*The name is a work in progress (although I may just call it that).
**Although I am not entirely sure, I think this location would probably be in a strait, at the confluence of two major rivers (a la St. Louis), or just in a really good harbor.
***I know that some historians will probably get upset at me by the use of the term collapse. I understand it would be accurate to say that most, if not all, empires in history declined or transitioned, not collapsed in an instant. However, at least from the vantage point of the region of focus, the Old Empire suddenly ceased to exist one day.

This kind of question fits into my "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin? Answer: as many as wanting" category. Or, said another way, "how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? Answer: He would chuck all the wood that a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood." Long story (and I mean that) short... you can write your story to easily rationalize any perspective on this you want, making it Too Story-Based. There is no deterministic answer. Do you want our help after you've made a choice?

Definitely over 9000 leverage. There isn't any useful leverage metric, furthermore leverage is entirely dependent upon relative positioning between parties. Trade in and of itself isn't leverage. If everyone can trade equally well there's no relative advantage. A relative advantage to trading can be rendered moot when there's limited value in trading. Having a leverage doesn't prevent parties from using leverage of their own to reach a less advantageous equilibrium. In addition to all that having leverage still requires that it is used effectively. Ultimately it's your world you get to decide.

We've added a chatroom to hopefully help work on some questions that don't fit the usual model particularly well, if you want some further input head over to Story Tellers Corner with your question and we'll see if we can help.

Look at Istanbul
So, I'd look to something like Istanbul/Constantinople in the medieval era for your model. Your city state does not just trade, it protects a means that everyone else uses to trade
That, in medieval times, is probably a narrow channel in the sea. Sure, you could take goods by land, but that's expensive. Sure, you could go round, but your ships may not be able to sail that far. Istanbul controls the only access to the Black Sea. In medieval times, it had a massive chain across the strait, stopping ships from sailing under certain conditions.
Now, your trade state. I'd place it on an island, in the middle of, possibly, a three way link between seas (one of which is possibly artificial). It is well defended, and everyone must use the narrow passages near it to get to another one of the seas.
Now, how does it maintain power? Well, from trade, it can't. It can collect tolls, but if it gets too greedy, it'll get invaded. It can restrict access, but restrict too much access, and it'll get invaded.
What it has to sell, really, is neutrality. The surrounding city states, while they'd all like to possess Okri, really, really do not want their rivals to do so. If Okri is smart, it can't really annex by treaty any other lands, but what it can do is get guarantees from other places that they'll respond if it is attacked.
Once it has those, though, it can get very rich. Okri can store money. After all, it's got like 17 countries blocking it from being invaded. Your wealth is safe there. It can loan money (and stop you passing if you don't pay, up to a point). And it can act as a safe trading hub for merchants, particularly when their own countries might be at war.
So, it exists in a uniquely fragile, uniquely wealthy spot. As its wealth grows, the incentives to invade it get higher. It can't really annex territory, because doing so would panic other countries. But it gets richer and richer

For a fictional example, Walder Frey in ASOIF owns the only bridge connecting two large portions of the continent. It's a defensible position and despite his territory being mostly marshes, he has an outsized influence on the politics of the continent. He could easily leverage that for trade in your scenario.

@RobinClower and from what I remember, it's played pretty similarly - at least until the treachery. He's a power broker in the realm, but he's not able to leverage that position to expand.

Most empires don't actually fall to dust; the normal thing that happens is that the empire fragments into a small number of still large-ish pieces, or a foreign power takes over. But yes, some empires did literally fall to dust, as exemplified by the complete self-destruction of the Western half of the Roman Empire in the 5th century CE.
Unfortunately, when the empire literally falls to dust there is no such thing as an advantageous location for trade, because there is no trade.
Fortunately, we do have an example of a city-state located in an advantageous position which after the fall of the Western Roman Empire endured and eventually became a great power. And yes it did base its power on trade, but only in the sense that its commercial wealth enabled it to maintain and project military force.
The Most Serene Republic of Venice
The Venetian Republic began as an small almost insignificant port town founded in the early 5th century on the northern shore of the Adriatic Sea. After the fall of the Western half of the empire, the fledgling Venice remained under the authority of the still functional Eastern Roman Empire, which enabled it to grow a little; but in the 7th century the Empire lost control over its territories in northern Italy, and Venice was left to fend for itself.
Which it did, quite successfully.
The major advantage that Venice had in its first centuries was not that it had and advantageous position for trade; it was that it had an advantageous position for defense. Its position on the lagoon enabled the city to survive the dark centuries of the early Middle Ages: which was of great importance, because by the late 8th century Venice emerged as basically the one and only fully functional city of the shores of the Adriatic, and the only full-service port open for trade.
Which made it the only statelet on the Adriatic to be rich enough to have some sort of military force, and notably a fleet.
Agile Venetian diplomacy resulted in formal treaties signed both with the (Eastern, but by this time the only) Roman Empire and the upstart Carolingian Empire; the city embarked in a successful round of long-distance slave trade, and the accumulated wealth only increased its military might.
Those were European slaves, mostly various kinds of Slavs from the Balkans and Central Europe, and Finno-Ugric people who at the time inhabited most what is now European Russia. The slaves were typically sold to Arabs, but also in some smaller number to Western European Christians.
Eventually, Venice pivoted away from basing its commercial revenue on the declining European slave trade and established itself as the main trading hub between the Christian Europe and the Muslim East. Its commercial wealth enabled the creation of a powerful fleet.
Venice annexed the Istrian Peninsula in the 10th century by force of arms, and then most of the Dalmatian coast by force of persuasion. (The Venetians were the only ones with a real fleet in the Adriatic, and the locals was sick and tired of pirate raids, so they willfully became Venetian subjects.) In the 13th century Venice took Euboea (which they called Negroponte) and the Greek islands in the Aegean, and most importantly Crete; in the 15th century they took Cyprus, and in the 17th century they took the Peloponnese (which they called Morea). It was the highest point of Venetian power.
And then it all fell down.
Because, in the end, the Stato da Màr was funded by commercial profits. Commercial profits are fine, but they cannot really compete in the long run with a real state which has its own people and its own internal production and its own internal market. Nobody has ever succeeded in basing an empire solely on trade.
By the 18th century Venice derived most of its revenue from the tourist trade, as it still does. But it was great while it lasted.

I applaud this answer I think it is the best real world example. Just for completeness: Venetian empire fell mainly for four reasons. 1. Atlantic trade become the place to make big money. 2. Their customers learnt to make a lot of goods Venetia previously exclusively traded. 3. conflicts with Habsburgs in which Venetia lost a lot influence in Adriatic. 4. blow were wars with Ottomans.
So it is pretty clear that Venetia held very well during what can be considered "post-collapse" period (and a bit beyond), but lost only against consolidated powers with built up "traditional economies".

What timeline are you living in where the Roman Empire literally crumbled to dust? Italy remained largely unified (together with parts of Illyria) under Odoacer, the Ostrogoths, and later the Lombards; Iberia was split into just two parts under the Suebi and Visigoths; Africa under the Vandals; Gaul under the Merovingians. Britannia was the only Diocese that could reasonably be described as crumbling into dust, and that's because it was actively abandoned (unlike the others)

That's the Western Roman Empire (after the withdrawal from Britain) split into just five successor states which would surely be in your "small number of still large-ish pieces" and "foreign power takes over" categories, not the crumbling into dust one

Even in cases like the Late Bronze Age Collapse where the Hittite Empire did fracture into a great many small Syro-Hittite states, trade networks in Phoenicia despite the collapse of the Hittites and the withdrawal of Egypt from the Levant (the two previous hegemons)

@Tristan: Yes, notionally Gaul became the Frankish Kingdom. In reality there was no functional government, neither at the level of the entire purely theoretical kingom nor at the level of the just a little less theoretical pieces such as Neustria or Aquitania. In practical reality each and every count and bishop ruled his little piece of land autonomously. Roads fell into disrepair, coined money fell out of use, trade was reduced to almost nothing. Italy fared a little better for a short while, as it maintained some sort of central (but ever changing) government for about 100 years.

@AlexP sure, the rule of law was weaker and infrastructure deteriorated, As for the lack of coinage, and trade being reduced to almost nothing, big citation needed. The Merovingians issued their own coins as early as the reign of Theudebert I, and earlier in the Merovingian period Byzantine coinage was used (proving not only the use of coined money, but also significant trade links with the wider world)

As for Italy, whilst again, central power was much weaker, it retained a single suzerain under Odoacer, the later Ostrogoths, and the Lombards, right up until the Charlemagne came along. The main exceptions are when external powers (most notably the Byzantines and the Aghlabids) conquered parts, and the Pope

the idea that rome "crumbled into dust" is a long outdated stereotype of the "dark ages" long consigned to the rubbish bin of historiography
